# How to fill Path with Image?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Given the following `GeometryReader(...)`:

```
GeometryReader { geo in
            Path  { path in
                let width = geo.size.width
                let height = geo.size.height * 0.40
                let litheight = geo.size.height * 0.24
                path.addLines([
                    CGPoint(x: 0, y: litheight),
                    CGPoint(x: width, y: height ),
                    CGPoint(x: width, y: 0),
                    CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
                ])
            }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

I want to set the top area with a background image.

I tried the following except it's not exactly what I'm after:

```
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Path  { path in
                let width = geo.size.width
                let height = geo.size.height * 0.40
                let litheight = geo.size.height * 0.24
                path.addLines([
                    CGPoint(x: 0, y: litheight),
                    CGPoint(x: width, y: height ),
                    CGPoint(x: width, y: 0),
                    CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
                ])
            }

            Image(systemName: "faceid")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

This is the result:

[image]

And this what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How to set Image as background of this path please ?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what exactly doesn't work with your approach?

Comment: I tried to put it in fill modifier, but it doesn't work, I tried to put as clipped path in my image but I can't to !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your image is in your `Assets.xcassets`.

Then you can achieve the result you're looking for by using : `fill(ImagePaint(...))`.

I would look at the documentation for other `ImagePaint` options [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagepaint).

```
GeometryReader { geo in 
    Path { path in
        let width = geo.size.width
        let height = geo.size.height * 0.40
        let litheight = geo.size.height * 0.24
        path.addLines([
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: litheight),
            CGPoint(x: width, y: height ),
            CGPoint(x: width, y: 0),
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        ])

    }
    .fill(ImagePaint(image:
        Image("background")
            .resizable()
        )
    )
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

[image]

Comment: @theMouk I have added a working solution now that I know what you're expecting.